# Android SQLite Exception Syntax Error (Code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, syntax

I'm creating a database using SQLiteHelper and I keep receiving exceptions when the app tries to run.

This is the error message that I receive :  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Trip": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table Business Trip Expenditure( desc text primary key , Meals integer NOT NULL , Drinks integer NOT NULL , Travel integer NOT NULL , Accommodation integer NOT NULL , Other integer NOT NULL , Receipt_Retained? real NOT NULL , Created_at text NOT NULL );

```js
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Business Trip Expenditure";
    //Column Names
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "desc";
    public static final String MEAL_COST ="Meals";
    public static final String DRINK_COST = "Drinks";
    public static final String TRAVEL_COST = "Travel";
    public static final String ACCO_COST = "Accommodation";
    public static final String OTHER_COST = "Other";
    public static final String HAS_RECEIPT = "Receipt_Retained?";
    public static final String CREATED_AT = "Created_at";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "task.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_NAME + "( " + COLUMN_NAME + " text primary key , " + MEAL_COST + " integer NOT NULL , " + DRINK_COST + " integer NOT NULL , " + TRAVEL_COST + " integer NOT NULL , " + ACCO_COST + " integer NOT NULL , " + OTHER_COST + " integer NOT NULL , " + HAS_RECEIPT + " real NOT NULL , " + CREATED_AT + " text NOT NULL );";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me with the syntax of the creation of the table it would be much appreciated, I know that this form of code is picky in terms of syntax.

Comment: You cannot have `space` in between the table name. Replace ot with some character like `_`.

Comment: @PrerakSola Actually **you can** (`public static final String TABLE_NAME = "[Business Trip Expenditure]";`). But you're **not encouraged** to.

Comment: Thank for he update @DerGolem. I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 3):

change :

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Business Trip Expenditure";
```

to

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Business_Trip_Expenditure";
```

Comment: OR... `public static final String TABLE_NAME = "[Business Trip Expenditure]";` (also valid, but **not encouraged**).

Comment: Thanks a lot haha, I have some major tunnel vision right now. Don't know how I didn't see that, thanks for your help.